# Using Stripe & Cognito Forms:

Tags: cognito-forms

I have added Stripe and require a payment of £0.99p. This is rejected with messsage "minimum $1" The Stripe website shows a minimum 50 cents. How do I get the payment of 99p accepted?

Answer (score 3):

I am a developer at [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

The $1 minimum is the minimum payment amount required by Cognito Forms. This minimum amount is set to ensure that the payment amount can cover Stripe’s fees of 2.9% + $.30 as well as Cognito Forms’ 1% fee. The $.50 minimum payment required by Stripe is set to ensure their transaction fees are covered, so we needed to raise that minimum enough to cover both sets of fees.

Comment: Thanks I understand, however £0.99 = 1.42 USD, is your answer still correct or can you update?

Comment: This is a current limitation.  We will look into whether Stripe will be able to assist us enough with the currency conversions to make this work.